# Rails 4.1.6 Pragmatic Rails NoMethodError at /line_items - undefined method `cart_url'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

There are several other question on Stack Overflow about *Iteration D3: Adding a Button*
in *Pragmatic Agile Web Development with Rails 4*, but I have looked through all of them and none seem to solve my problem.

When I attempt to add an item to the cart, I get the following error:

[image]

Below is my LineItemController's `create` method:

```
      def create
    @item = Item.find(params[:item_id])
    @line_item = @cart.line_items.build(:item_id => :item_id)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @line_item.save
        format.html { redirect_to @line_item.cart,
          notice: 'Line item was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show',
          status: :created, location: @line_item }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @line_item.errors,
          status: :unprocessable_entity  }
      end
    end
  end
```

Any help would be appreciated, I've been at this for quite a while.  Thank you.

EDIT:

This is my routes file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :users
  resources :items
  resources :line_items

  root 'static_pages#home'
  get 'about'         => 'static_pages#about'
  get 'items'         => 'items#index'
  get 'signup'        => 'users#new'
  get 'login'         => 'sessions#new'
  post 'login'        => 'sessions#create'
  delete 'logout'     => 'sessions#destroy'
  get 'catalog'       => 'catalog#index'
```

Comment: You have no route for showing a `cart`, whatever that is.

Comment: I should add a route for line_items#show?

Answer (score 0):

You should have a `resources :carts` entry in your `config/routes.rb` file.

May be you skipped that part of the tutorial...

Comment: I added the resources:carts to the routes.rb just now actually.  What's strange is that when I add an item, I get the notice that it was added, but I get a new error: **undefined method `title' for nil:NilClass**

Comment: I'm reading that chapter right now... The line should have been added automatically when you run the line `rails generate scaffold Cart` (you are meant to run that in chapter `9.1 Iteration D1: Finding a Cart`. To solve the error that you are explaining in your comment is needed more information (probably in a new question)